# sql query to calculate sum of agroup counts

Tags: php, mysql

**fields**       id ,party,votes

my query getting o/p like this

```
 partyname    bjp      aap         congress   

  votes        1        2              2
```

**but i also need sum of votes. below is my expected output.**

```
  BJP         aap           congress       total

   1             2            2             5

SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, COUNT( RES.CONSTITUENCY )
        AS VOTESCOUNT FROM voter_count RES JOIN (SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX( VOTES )
        AS VOTES FROM voter_count GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY)MAXS USING ( VOTES, CONSTITUENCY )
        GROUP BY PARTYNAME LIMIT 0 , 1000";
```

Comment: Kindly post a sqlfidlle, your question is not clear. Moreover your sql query has more tables.  Add proper structured schema for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

SELECT SUM(something) AS something, SUM(else) AS else FROM stuff

Just an idea how you can get the SUM

Answer (score 0):

According to your table,

```
SELECT SUM(partyname) AS total_parties, SUM(votes) AS total_votes FROM table_name;
```

is this what you want?? Your question is not clear & query is irrelavant to description...