# sql query to get sum of count values

Tags: php, mysql

```
   aap      bjp       congress          sum
    1        2           5               8
```

**i want to display sum of votescount.** like above table output.

below is my sql query

**plz suggest me how to get sum of echo votescount.**

```
SELECT RES.PARTYNAME,COUNT( RES.CONSTITUENCY ) AS VOTESCOUNT FROM voter_count RES  JOIN (SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES FROM voter_count
        GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY)MAXS USING ( VOTES, CONSTITUENCY )  GROUP BY PARTYNAME  LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Comment: i have posted my table db structure table name voter_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below query should work for you:

```
SELECT SUM(x.VOTESCOUNT) AS VOTESUM FROM ( 
SELECT RES.PARTYNAME,COUNT( RES.CONSTITUENCY ) AS VOTESCOUNT FROM voter_count RES  JOIN (SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES FROM voter_count GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY)MAXS USING ( VOTES, CONSTITUENCY )  GROUP BY PARTYNAME  LIMIT 0 ,1000
) x;
```

VOTESUM will give you total sum of VOTESCOUNT

Answer (score 0):

According to your table,

```
SELECT SUM(partyname) AS total_parties, SUM(votes) AS total_votes FROM table_name;
```

is this what you want?? Your question is not clear & query is irrelavant to description...

duplicate of [sql query to calculate sum of agroup counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312462/sql-query-to-calculate-sum-of-agroup-counts/26313058#26313058)

Answer (score 0):

If your column values are per-defined then you can use below static query

```
SELECT
       count(CASE WHEN partyname = 'BJP' THEN pagecount END) `BJP`,
       count(CASE WHEN partyname = 'AAP' THEN pagecount END) `AAP`,
       count(CASE WHEN partyname = 'Other' THEN pagecount END) `Other` ,

       count(CASE WHEN partyname = 'BJP' THEN pagecount END) +
       count(CASE WHEN partyname = 'AAP' THEN pagecount END)+ 
       count(CASE WHEN partyname = 'Other' THEN pagecount END) `Sum` 
  FROM test_vote
```

You can use [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59c0d/10) link, i have created with sample data.

If you want to have dynamic columns, than you can  use [PIVOT](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table) table which will give you dynamic output in tabular format.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

select (select sum(votes) from table),partyName , count(id) from table group by partyname

select sum(votes) from table //give total votes // rest give party name wise votes